# redis command-line commands seem not working

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, redis

I have a silly problem with running redis commands in ubuntu 12 terminal , maybe my question is silly , if so , consider I'm a newbie user of redis and ubuntu.

I have installed redis 2.6.7 according to the official guide http://redis.io/download

Now I run these commands :

```
redis-server
```

It says it's now connected but after that nothing happens after each command I enter, so I press (Ctrl + z) and then type :

```
redis-cli
```

and it seems to connect successfully and something like this appears :

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

So I type some commands but nothing happens. for example this command :

```
get users:leto
```

and just a blank line appears. (seems it's waiting for something to complete the command)

So what's the problem according to this? am I missing a simple point or there's another problem?

Thanks for your help , I'm really confused.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that you have suspended `redis-server` by pressing `Ctrl+Z`, so it cannot respond to anything (`redis-cli` probably did not connect to the server but it is written so that it doesn't fail immediately in such case). You can resume `redis-server` in background by issuing `bg` command after pressing `Ctrl+Z`.

I would suggest you to read about job control in UNIX shells to understand this issue better.

Comment: thank you, iv'e been looking for an answer to this problem, and after many a searches this was the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple solution is at the bottom if you are in hurry.**

I've met the same problem, facing a running redis server and types command and wait it until bored. And I even don't know there is a redis-cli command!

After I saw this question. I went back to my terminal and type redis-cli into my redis-sever terminal screen. As you know, nothing happens still.

But a great idea hit me. I opened another terminal, and type into redis-cli.

```
redis-cli
```

Now a pretty redis interface prompt out, looks like

```
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Wow! Thrilling. Let's try if it works

```
127.0.0.1:6379>APPEND zen Solver_of_this_problem
(interger) 22
127.0.0.1:6379>GET zen
'Solver_of_this_problem'
```

Awesome! I can handle my redis now!

So the secret is:

## Open two terminals, one for redis-sever, and another for redis-cli.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was connecting to a tls enabled redis server so the prompt was hanging. adding `--tls` fixed this for me.